# How can i order the columns of a grid from my c# code

Tags: c#, datagridview, grid, telerik, telerik-grid

Is there a way i can show the column of a telerik grid a defined order from the code?

```
   list.Add(objFromCDF);
   radGridCloseCard.DataSource = list;
```

This is the way i am filling the grid in my c# code. Using this method is giving me an error:

```
    radGridCloseCard.Columns["Customer_No"].ToString().DisplayIndex = 0;
```

The error says "The best overloaded method match for 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridColumnCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: `ToString ().DisplayIndex` is wrong, try removing ToString, it's the Column that has the method DisplayIndex

Comment: @JeremyThompson even without ToString() gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are using `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`.

In order to specify the orders, you must specify each columns in the  tag and set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.

The order in which you specify the columns is the same used to display those columns.

Comment: The order in which you specify the columns is the same used to display those columns.  You mean the order i Bound them in the aspx file or what?